# Android login app error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have made a login app in android .The user gets logged in after giving the correct EMail-id and password but after logging in when i press the back button in my phone i again get redirected to the previous page i.e to my login page. I want to restrict this that when a user is logged in and if he/she presses the back button the user should remain in that page only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function `onBackPressed()` which you may override. Leave it empty if you don't want it at all. Requires API level 5 (i.e. android 2.0 or later) As such:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After validating the credentials in the log-in page call `finish()` immediately after `startActivity(intentobj)` statement.